# Zend Project architecture

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3

I'm currently using Zend 3 for a project (or a range of projects). In order to avoid multiple `vendor` folders per project, I'd like to have ONE `vendor` folder at root level that every project runs from.

In my application `/public/index.php` file, I have changed this line:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to this:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../shared/vendor/autoload.php';
```

When I did this, I saw this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException with message Module (Application) could not be initialized. in C:\Users\b28934\Documents\server\UwAmp\www\zf3\app\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php on line 203"

Any suggestions? Is there something I'm missing in my `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all there is no need of having only one `vendor` folder for all projects. Drive space is cheap nowadays. I see definitely no reason.
2. It is by design, that every composer project has its own `vendor` folder, because it would fail if you had 2 projects which require the same package but in *different* versions.

I suggest keep it simple. Keep it like it is designed by smart people. And don't try to mess it up for no reason.

Comment: With regards to your first point, memory isn't the issue. I'm hoping to use the same vendor folder managed by one composer.json file that'd be used used by all four web applications. In a case where I'd introduce a new module / package via composer, rather than updating each websites vendor folder (via composer one at a time), it'd make sense to update one composer.json file and one vendor folder, and let that transpire across all other web applications.

Comment: No. Time will come when you need package `foo/A` in project 1 and package `foo/B` in project 2. And if `foo/A` depends on `foo/C` version 1 and `foo/B` depends on `foo/C` version 2 then everything is messed up. I've see seen *some* people that thought like you and every time these people ended with a messed up setup and needed to return to one project one `vendor` folder philosophy. This is a well elaborated mechanism. It's easier to copy the `composer.json` and run update on each project and keep them independent. In case of any issues you are able to keep them on different dependencies.